# SharePoint Dropdown Vaue not updating in to Dataview webpart with SQL backend

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, sql-server

I have a data view webpart and its source is a sql server database table(2005).  I have the data view setup to be able to edit some of the fields inside the dataview.  Instead of providing the user with a textbox to edit the values I would like to provide a dropdown list with specific values that the user can select from.I got the dropdown and made sure the selected values are perfect but  I haven't been successful while I hit the save button its not taking my dropdown value its just showing the previous value which was already in that field that means its not updating the dropdown value but its working perfect if it is textbox.  Does anyone know how this is done in Sharepoint Designer tool ? I have been hitting the google for past 2 days so it would be great if any of one have the solution for this issue.

It looks like everything is good but I dont know for some reasons dropdown values are not updating to the datasource. Do I miss something??Please let me know Thanks 
Vinodh Sankaran

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before when I would add a field from the SQL Server data source and make it a dropdown box.  The solution, as strange as it seems, was to not drag the dropdown from the data source, but rather add it manually and then bind it to the appropriate field.  Taking this approach it seemed to work.

I blogged about it last year.  This will walk you through the process.  You are interested in "Part 3":
http://sharepointblog.kellerschroeder.com/search/label/SQL%20Server